# GPS Device using non-proprietary software and connector

Tags: gps, hardware-recommendations

Are there GPS devices that use non-proprietary software and connector? Ideally USB C for the connector. I've been using my Android phone with GPS Essentials and am frustrated by the constant dropping of tracking by the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garmin used to make a unit called the [Monterra](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/113522), which sounds like what you're after: it has a mini-USB port, runs on Android and you can install other apps on it from the Google Play store. I don't think they make them anymore and as far as I can tell none of their current units offer the ability to install your own apps on them, though most of their current units have USB ports. I think they've stuck with mini-USB ports because the port is more sturdy than micro-USB. USB Type-C is still very new, I don't think we'll be seeing it in outdoorsy GPS units for a while.

If you just need a better GPS location on your phone, you can keep your current phone and get a bluetooth-enabled GPS receiver like the Garmin GLO, Bad Elf, or Dual XGPS.

Comment: Found out the some people at work use Bad Elf devices and they spoke positively about them.